# Angular put method does not work, but Postman does

Tags: angular, http, put

I have problem with put method in Angular. In Postman everything works. Here is my cod.

app.component.ts

```
x = localStorage.getItem('Id')
  online:number = +this.x;

 if(this.online != null){
    this.ls.online(this.online);
    console.log(this.online);
  }
```

In my service it looks like:

```
 online(id){
    return this.http.put('http://localhost:5000/getImage/online', id);
  }
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The observable returned by the Angular HttpClient is cold. You need to subscribe to it to trigger the request: `this.ls.online(this.online).subscribe(res => console.log(res), err => console.log(err));`

Comment: Then i get:  PUT http://localhost:5000/getImage/online 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to solve that issue. One glaring issue I see is you're assigning the value of `this.x` to `online`. But end up using `this.online` member variable for the request. Are you sure both are same values?

Comment: Even if I set value id in service I get the same error. I use two variables because when i get id from localstorage i get it in string like this '5'. Because of that I get id with variable x and make number of it in variable online. But I say even if I set value directly I get an error

Comment: You'd have to compare the request here against Postman's. Check if the expected body of the request is indeed of type number.

Comment: Indeed, you can instect the request in Chrome's (or whatever) console, and see the real content and uri. Then you can compare it to the postman's request.